# Proof that the equations of motion of the relativistic EM Hamiltonian are gauge invariant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, gauge-invariance

Considering the relativistic EM Hamiltonian
$$ H(\vec{q}, \vec{p}) = \sqrt{m^2c^4 + c^2(\vec{p} - e\vec{A})^2} + e\phi,$$
is there any proof of the gauge invariance of the corresponding equations of motion? If I use another vector potential $\vec{A}' = \vec{A} + \nabla \lambda$ I can't see at a glance that the EOM remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you gauge transform A and phi you are correct the equation of motion will not be immediately invariant. But the point is, you can do a canonical transformation and redefine p and q such as to absorb the gauge transformation and remake the equation of motion invariant again.

This is immediately reminiscent in QED where a gauge transform of $A^{\mu}$ must be accompanied by a gauge transformation of the dirac field $\Psi$ to make the QED lagrangian gauge invariant.

It is in this sense, gauge transform + canonical transform, that your hamiltonian is still gauge invariant.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: suppose I have the vector potential $\vec{A}$, I get Hamilton's equation and I solve them numerically, obtaining a trajectory. If now I apply a gauge transformation and I solve again the resulting Hamilton's equations I would expect to get the same trajectory (even if Hamilton's equation are different) since the particle is moving in the same field. It is true and possible to prove it?

Comment: If you apply the canonical transformation $\vec R = \vec r$, $\vec P = \vec p + Q∇Λ(r, t)$  to your hamiltonian, you will see that the equation of motions describe a particle moving in the gauge transformed potentials A′ = A + c∇Λ(r, t),  and  φ′ = φ − $\frac{\partial \Lambda}{\partial t}$. Thus if you apply a gauge transformation to your hamiltonian above you will see that the equations of motion describe a particle whose dynamical coordinates are canonical transformations of your original coordinates.

Comment: The effect of a gauge transform is a canonical transform, or the effect of a canonical transform is a gauge transformation, either way hamilton's equations are invariant.